# How to slow bouncing balls in MDN tutorial

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am following [MDN's Object Building Practice tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_building_practice), attempting to complete the tutorial using the ES6 class declarations.

The bouncing balls in my program are moving much faster than the tutorial outlines. I have set the velocity of the newly created Ball instances; however, the Ball instances are still moving too quickly.

```
// setup canvas

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// function to generate random number

function random(min, max) {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;
    return num;
}

class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, velX, velY, color, size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }

    update() {
        if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
        }
        if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
        }
        if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
        }
        if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
        }
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
    };

}


function loop() {
    let balls = [];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    while (balls.length < 25) {
        let size = random(10,20);
        let ball = new Ball(
            // ball position always drawn at least one ball width
            // away from the edge of the canvas, to avoid drawing errors
            random(0 + size,width - size),
            random(0 + size,height - size),
            5,
            5,
            'rgb(' + random(0,255) + ',' + random(0,255) + ',' + random(0,255) +')',
            size
        );
        balls.push(ball);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        balls[i].draw();
        balls[i].update();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you put `let balls = []` inside loop function.

Just move it to the outside and everything will start to work.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// function to generate random number

function random(min, max) {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
}

class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, velX, velY, color, size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }

    update() {
        if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
        }
        if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velX = -(this.velX);
        }
        if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
        }
        if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
            this.velY = -(this.velY);
        }
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
    };

}


let balls = []; // moved outside loop() function

function loop() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    while (balls.length < 25) {
        let size = random(10,20);
        let ball = new Ball(
            // ball position always drawn at least one ball width
            // away from the edge of the canvas, to avoid drawing errors
            random(0 + size,width - size),
            random(0 + size,height - size),
            5,
            5,
            'rgb(' + random(0,255) + ',' + random(0,255) + ',' + random(0,255) +')',
            size
        );
        balls.push(ball);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        balls[i].draw();
        balls[i].update();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The only thing I did was checking your code against the tutorial's code. Always recheck the steps you did when you encouter a code problem.